# How to intersect the type of a function argument based on the value of another argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Here is a basic `User` class:

```js
class User< U > {

    private _user: Partial< U > = {};

    public set< K extends keyof U >(

        key: K,
        val: U[ K ],

    ) : void {

        this._user[ key ] = val;

    }
}
```

And a basic `Employee` interface:

```js
interface Employee {

    name: string;
    city: string;
    role: number;

}
```

---

Now, consider the following implementation:

```js
const admin = new User< Employee >();

admin.set( "name", 10 );
```

The above script yields the following error which is expected.

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Now take a look at the following implementation:

```js
const admin = new User< Employee >();

admin.set< "name" | "role" >( "name", 10 );
```

The above script does not yield any error and it is also expected, as long as `10` is assignable to `name` or `role`.

To make it more clear, let's take a look at the following script:

```js
const admin = new User< Employee >();

admin.set< "name" | "role" >( "name", true );
```

The above script yields the following error which is also expected.

> Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.

---

Now, what I want to achieve is, `10` should not be allowed to be stored as a value of `name` at any mean.

For this, I need to make some changes to my code something similar to the followings:

```js
public set< K extends keyof U >(

    key: K,
    val: U[ valueof key ],

) : void {

    this._user[ key ] = val;

}
```

But as long as there is nothing like `valueof key`, this cannot be achieved dynamically.

For testing, if you replace `U[ K ]` by `U[ "name" ]`, you will see `10` is no longer allowed anymore at any form.

However, is there any way to achieve my goal?

Many programmers solved similar problems by applying `T[ keyof T ]` which I think is not applicable to this case.

Thanks in advance.

**[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOAeO0B80DeAoX0h0ADkgJYBuYALgtAPoCuiSAXNAAphLVlghpYmaAF4cAXwDc+IiUYAjEGWDRE1NAGloCAB60AdgBMYAawQBPAPYAzdBgAUM2UTPn2GgDQFnhKiHawANrQWgC6Xt6EAJTQ7BSWZIY4Tj7UABZkEAB0TCzBrtChotB+0pHQ4riVuGT6tEjWYMB0AKIAtsQgluYIdHjl+mBtCOwQ1OT6AObSssBk1G6q47XT5UiWICPQ+oxt8shl1cCW+mPQYIZttcX6CADucCxo7Z3dvZj2UWUXV-pZavZoAAiQbDIEeaAARgADNAvrgfrV-gh1MDQQggdAAD7A9abTEONFDDEQmFw6SIv5qNAg4mYnFAvEYj5EsEQ8aMOjwoA)**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to say that K can only be one particular key and not a union of keys.  So there is no way to say that the U[K] can only be one value.

What you have done is the best that you can do.  Typescript will always infer the correct K if you are passing a string literal value.

An alternative would be to have a set function which takes Partial and pass the key and value together as an object.  This ensures that the key and value must always match each other.  But it also changes your usage in a way that is probably undesirable.

Comment: Thanks for your contributing @Linda. Perhaps TypeScript will offer this feature in future.